# Multiple definition of main() , vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, multiple-definition-error

I am writing entry level program in visual studio code which looks like the screenshot attached. 
I am not able to resolve this error,

```
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCMGIfQ.o: In function `main':
D:\vscode/main.cpp:3: multiple definition of `main'
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjmxAV5.o:D:\vscode/main.cpp:3: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I have read posts on stack as well as a couple of websites without any results.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You compile main.cpp twice: `Execution task: "g++ -g main.cpp" -g main.cpp` ???

Comment: You have `-g main.cpp` twice on the command line. There's a problem with your VSCode configuration.

Comment: In the future, please don't post images of text or links to images of text. Post the text.

Comment: Due to screenshot you try to compile main.cpp two times. I believe that causes the issue. Just try to edit your compilation configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much. There was a problem with launch.json file.

Comment: @molbdilo I will keep it in mind.